# Getting a Metadata file 'Microsoft.CSharp' could not be found error upon trying to export a fastreport report

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, fastreport

Trying to use fastreport opensource version to prepare and export a report to pdf
Using Microsoft Sql Server database as datasource for it
My code seemingly connects to the database and is able to fill the datasource so most likely the problem is somewhere in the code that creates the report itself , but i dont exactly see where it could happen

Exception occurs in report.Prepare();
and the line after it

```
 using FastReport;
 using FastReport.Data;
 using FastReport.Export.Image;
 using FastReport.Export.PdfSimple;
 using FastReport.Format;
 using FastReport.Table;
 using FastReport.Utils;
 using System;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Windows;

 namespace KursovayaAvtoparkAvtobusov
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for ReportExport.xaml
     /// </summary>
     public partial class ReportExport : Window
     {
         private static string outFolder = @"..\..\..\out\";
         private static string inFolder = @"..\..\..\in\";

         public ReportExport()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void SimpleRepExport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {

             Report report = new Report();
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
             sqlConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KursovayaAvtoparkAvtobusov"].ToString();
             sqlConnection.Open();
             var select = "SELECT * FROM Employees; SELECT* FROM Maintenance; SELECT* FROM Marshuti; SELECT* FROM Prodazhi";
             var commandBuilder = new SqlCommand(select, sqlConnection);
             commandBuilder.ExecuteNonQuery();

             var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandBuilder);
             adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Employees");
             adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Maintenance");
             adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "Marshuti");
             adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table3", "Prodazhi");
             adapter.Fill(ds);
             MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].TableName);
             MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[1].TableName);
             MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[2].TableName);
             MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[3].TableName);
             report.RegisterData(ds.Tables["Employees"], "Employees");
             // enable it to use in a report
             report.GetDataSource("Employees").Enabled = true;
             // create A4 page with all margins set to 1cm
             ReportPage page1 = new ReportPage();
             page1.Name = "Page1";
             report.Pages.Add(page1);
             // create a ReportTitle band
             page1.ReportTitle = new ReportTitleBand();
             page1.ReportTitle.Name = "ReportTitle1";
             // set its height to 1.5cm
             page1.ReportTitle.Height = Units.Centimeters * 1.5f;
             // create group header
             GroupHeaderBand group1 = new GroupHeaderBand();
             group1.Name = "GroupHeader1";
             group1.Height = Units.Centimeters * 1;
             // set group condition
             group1.Condition = "[Employees.Surname].Substring(0, 1)";
             // add group to the page.Bands collection
             page1.Bands.Add(group1);
             // create group footer
             group1.GroupFooter = new GroupFooterBand();
             group1.GroupFooter.Name = "GroupFooter1";
             group1.GroupFooter.Height = Units.Centimeters * 1;
             // create DataBand
             DataBand data1 = new DataBand();
             data1.Name = "Data1";
             data1.Height = Units.Centimeters * 0.5f;
             // set data source
             data1.DataSource = report.GetDataSource("Employees");
             // connect databand to a group
             group1.Data = data1;
             // create "Text" objects
             // report title
             TextObject text1 = new TextObject();
             text1.Name = "Text1";
             // set bounds
             text1.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0,
             Units.Centimeters * 19, Units.Centimeters * 1);
             // set text
             text1.Text = "Employees";
             // set appearance
             text1.HorzAlign = HorzAlign.Center;
             text1.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 14);
             // add it to ReportTitle
             page1.ReportTitle.Objects.Add(text1);
             // group
             TextObject text2 = new TextObject();
             text2.Name = "Text2";
             text2.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0,
             Units.Centimeters * 2, Units.Centimeters * 1);
             text2.Text = "[[Employees.Name].Substring(0, 1)]";
             text2.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 10);
             // add it to the GroupHeader
             group1.Objects.Add(text2);
             // data band
             TextObject text3 = new TextObject();
             text3.Name = "Text3";
             text3.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0,
             Units.Centimeters * 10, Units.Centimeters * 0.5f);
             text3.Text = "[Employees.Patronym]";
             text3.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8);
             // add it to DataBand
             data1.Objects.Add(text3);
             report.Prepare();
             PDFSimpleExport pdf = new PDFSimpleExport();
             // Save the report 
             report.Export(pdf, "ExportedPDF.pdf");
         }
     }
 }
```

Source code in the file

Exception details

```
FastReport.Utils.CompilerException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=(0,0): Error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.CSharp' could not be found

  Source=FastReport
  StackTrace:
   at FastReport.Code.AssemblyDescriptor.InternalCompile()
   at FastReport.Code.AssemblyDescriptor.Compile()
   at FastReport.Report.Prepare(Boolean append)
   at KursovayaAvtoparkAvtobusov.ReportExport.SimpleRepExport_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\AndreySavich\source\repos\KursovayaAvtoparkAvtobusov\KursovayaAvtoparkAvtobusov\ReportExport.xaml.cs:line 117
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at KursovayaAvtoparkAvtobusov.App.Main()
```

Expected behavior would be an exported to a  pdf file report which can be viewed in pdf viewers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And i managed to fix it
Basically the cause for that error was using the wrong type of sqlconnection
Reworked the code from
this

```html
 using FastReport;
 using FastReport.Data;
 using FastReport.Export.Image;
 using FastReport.Export.PdfSimple;
 using FastReport.Format;
 using FastReport.Table;
 using FastReport.Utils;
 using System;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Windows;

 namespace KursovayaAvtoparkAvtobusov
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for ReportExport.xaml
     /// </summary>
     public partial class ReportExport : Window
     {
         private static string outFolder = @"..\..\..\out\";
         private static string inFolder = @"..\..\..\in\";

         public ReportExport()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void SimpleRepExport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {

             Report report = new Report();
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
             sqlConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KursovayaAvtoparkAvtobusov"].ToString();
             sqlConnection.Open();
             var select = "SELECT * FROM Employees; SELECT* FROM Maintenance; SELECT* FROM Marshuti; SELECT* FROM Prodazhi";
             var commandBuilder = new SqlCommand(select, sqlConnection);
             commandBuilder.ExecuteNonQuery();

             var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandBuilder);
             adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Employees");
             adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Maintenance");
             adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "Marshuti");
             adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table3", "Prodazhi");
             adapter.Fill(ds);
             MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].TableName);
             MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[1].TableName);
             MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[2].TableName);
             MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[3].TableName);
             report.RegisterData(ds.Tables["Employees"], "Employees");
             // enable it to use in a report
             report.GetDataSource("Employees").Enabled = true;
             // create A4 page with all margins set to 1cm
             ReportPage page1 = new ReportPage();
             page1.Name = "Page1";
             report.Pages.Add(page1);
             // create a ReportTitle band
             page1.ReportTitle = new ReportTitleBand();
             page1.ReportTitle.Name = "ReportTitle1";
             // set its height to 1.5cm
             page1.ReportTitle.Height = Units.Centimeters * 1.5f;
             // create group header
             GroupHeaderBand group1 = new GroupHeaderBand();
             group1.Name = "GroupHeader1";
             group1.Height = Units.Centimeters * 1;
             // set group condition
             group1.Condition = "[Employees.Surname].Substring(0, 1)";
             // add group to the page.Bands collection
             page1.Bands.Add(group1);
             // create group footer
             group1.GroupFooter = new GroupFooterBand();
             group1.GroupFooter.Name = "GroupFooter1";
             group1.GroupFooter.Height = Units.Centimeters * 1;
             // create DataBand
             DataBand data1 = new DataBand();
             data1.Name = "Data1";
             data1.Height = Units.Centimeters * 0.5f;
             // set data source
             data1.DataSource = report.GetDataSource("Employees");
             // connect databand to a group
             group1.Data = data1;
             // create "Text" objects
             // report title
             TextObject text1 = new TextObject();
             text1.Name = "Text1";
             // set bounds
             text1.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0,
             Units.Centimeters * 19, Units.Centimeters * 1);
             // set text
             text1.Text = "Employees";
             // set appearance
             text1.HorzAlign = HorzAlign.Center;
             text1.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 14);
             // add it to ReportTitle
             page1.ReportTitle.Objects.Add(text1);
             // group
             TextObject text2 = new TextObject();
             text2.Name = "Text2";
             text2.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0,
             Units.Centimeters * 2, Units.Centimeters * 1);
             text2.Text = "[[Employees.Name].Substring(0, 1)]";
             text2.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 10);
             // add it to the GroupHeader
             group1.Objects.Add(text2);
             // data band
             TextObject text3 = new TextObject();
             text3.Name = "Text3";
             text3.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0,
             Units.Centimeters * 10, Units.Centimeters * 0.5f);
             text3.Text = "[Employees.Patronym]";
             text3.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 8);
             // add it to DataBand
             data1.Objects.Add(text3);
             report.Prepare();
             PDFSimpleExport pdf = new PDFSimpleExport();
             // Save the report 
             report.Export(pdf, "ExportedPDF.pdf");
         }
     }
 }
```

to this

```html
using FastReport;
using FastReport.Data;

using FastReport.Export.Image;
using FastReport.Export.PdfSimple;
using FastReport.Format;
using FastReport.Table;
using FastReport.Utils;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace KursovayaAvtoparkAvtobusov
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ReportExport.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ReportExport : Window
    {
        private static string outFolder = @"..\..\..\out\";
        private static string inFolder = @"..\..\..\in\";

        public ReportExport()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /*private void Fucttardmethod()
        {
            RegisteredObjects.AddConnection(typeof(MsSqlDataConnection));
            Report report = new Report();

            MsSqlDataConnection sqlConnection = new MsSqlDataConnection();
            sqlConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KursovayaAvtoparkAvtobusov"].ToString();
            sqlConnection.CreateAllTables();
            report.Report.Dictionary.Connections.Add(sqlConnection);
            var select = "SELECT * FROM Employees; SELECT* FROM Maintenance; SELECT* FROM Marshuti; SELECT* FROM Prodazhi";

            report.GetDataSource("Employees").Enabled = true;
            report.GetDataSource("Maintenance").Enabled = true;
            report.GetDataSource("Marshuti").Enabled = true;
            report.GetDataSource("Prodazhi").Enabled = true;

            report.Prepare();
            PDFSimpleExport pdf = new PDFSimpleExport();
            // Save the report 
            report.Export(pdf, "ExportedPDF.pdf");
        }*/

        private void SimpleRepExport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RegisteredObjects.AddConnection(typeof(MsSqlDataConnection));
            Report report = new Report();

            MsSqlDataConnection connection = new MsSqlDataConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KursovayaAvtoparkAvtobusov"].ToString();
            connection.CreateAllTables();
            report.Dictionary.Connections.Add(connection);
            report.RegisterData(connection.DataSet, "mssql");
            report.GetDataSource("Employees").Enabled = true;

            ReportPage page = new ReportPage();

            report.Pages.Add(page);
            page.CreateUniqueName();
            page.TopMargin = 10.0f;
            page.LeftMargin = 10.0f;
            page.RightMargin = 10.0f;
            page.BottomMargin = 10.0f;
            DataBand data = new DataBand();

            data.CreateUniqueName();
            page.AddChild(data);
            data.DataSource = report.GetDataSource("Employees"); //adding a table to a bend
            data.Height = Units.Centimeters * 5f;
            // Creating report title
            page.ReportTitle = new ReportTitleBand();
            page.ReportTitle.CreateUniqueName();
            page.ReportTitle.Height = 4.0f * Units.Centimeters;
            TextObject titleText = new TextObject();
            titleText.CreateUniqueName();
            titleText.Left = 1.0f * Units.Centimeters;
            titleText.Top = 1.0f * Units.Centimeters;
            titleText.Width = 17.0f * Units.Centimeters;
            titleText.Height = 2.0f * Units.Centimeters;
            titleText.HorzAlign = HorzAlign.Center;
            titleText.VertAlign = VertAlign.Center;
            titleText.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 32.0f);
            titleText.TextColor = Color.Black;
            titleText.FillColor = Color.Wheat;
            titleText.Border.Color = Color.Black;
            titleText.Border.Lines = BorderLines.All;
            titleText.Border.Width = 4.0f;
            titleText.Text = "Avtopark Report";
            page.ReportTitle.Objects.Add(titleText);
            // Header object
            TextObject headerText = new TextObject();
            headerText.CreateUniqueName();
            headerText.Bounds = new RectangleF(0.0f, 2.7f * Units.Centimeters,
                19.0f * Units.Centimeters, 1.0f * Units.Centimeters);
            headerText.HorzAlign = HorzAlign.Center;
            headerText.VertAlign = VertAlign.Center;
            headerText.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 16.0f);
            headerText.TextColor = Color.Black;
            headerText.FillColor = Color.Wheat;
            headerText.Border.Color = Color.Black;
            headerText.Border.Lines = BorderLines.All;
            headerText.Border.Width = 4.0f;
            headerText.Text = "Employees" + " Table";
            page.ReportTitle.Objects.Add(headerText);

            // Text bands
            TextObject bandText = new TextObject();
            bandText.CreateUniqueName();
            bandText.HorzAlign = HorzAlign.Center;
            bandText.Bounds = new RectangleF(0.0f * Units.Centimeters, 0.25f,
                1.0f * Units.Centimeters, 0.5f * Units.Centimeters);

            bandText.Border.Lines = BorderLines.All;

            bandText.Text = "[Employees.Num]";
            data.AddChild(bandText);
            TextObject text1 = new TextObject();
            text1.Parent = data;
            text1.CreateUniqueName();
            text1.Bounds = new RectangleF(1 * Units.Centimeters, 0, Units.Centimeters * 3, Units.Centimeters * 0.5f);

            text1.Text = "[Employees.Surname]"; //table and its field
            text1.Border.Lines = BorderLines.All;
            TextObject text2 = new TextObject();
            text2.Parent = data;
            text2.CreateUniqueName();
            text2.Bounds = new RectangleF(4 * Units.Centimeters, 0, Units.Centimeters * 20, Units.Centimeters * 0.5f);

            text2.Text = "[Employees.Name]"; //table and its field
            text2.Border.Lines = BorderLines.All;
            TextObject text3 = new TextObject();
            text3.Parent = data;
            text3.CreateUniqueName();
            text3.Bounds = new RectangleF(10 * Units.Centimeters, 0, Units.Centimeters * 15, Units.Centimeters * 0.5f);

            text3.Text = "[Employees.Patronym]"; //table and its field
            text3.Border.Lines = BorderLines.All;
            TextObject text4 = new TextObject();
            text4.Parent = data;
            text4.CreateUniqueName();
            text4.Bounds = new RectangleF(13 * Units.Centimeters, 0, Units.Centimeters * 5, Units.Centimeters * 0.5f);

            text4.Text = "[Employees.Employed_Since]"; //table and its field
            text4.Border.Lines = BorderLines.All;
            TextObject text5 = new TextObject();
            text5.Parent = data;
            text5.CreateUniqueName();
            text5.Bounds = new RectangleF(15 * Units.Centimeters, 0, Units.Centimeters * 5, Units.Centimeters * 0.5f);

            text5.Text = "[Employees.Job]"; //table and its field
            text5.Border.Lines = BorderLines.All;
            TextObject text6 = new TextObject();
            text6.Parent = data;
            text6.CreateUniqueName();
            text6.Bounds = new RectangleF(18 * Units.Centimeters, 0, Units.Centimeters * 5, Units.Centimeters * 0.5f);

            text6.Text = "[Employees.Internship]"; //table and its field
            text6.Border.Lines = BorderLines.All;
            // Footer
            page.PageFooter = new PageFooterBand();
            page.PageFooter.CreateUniqueName();
            page.PageFooter.Height = 0.5f * Units.Centimeters;

            TextObject footerText = new TextObject();
            footerText.CreateUniqueName();
            footerText.HorzAlign = HorzAlign.Right;
            footerText.VertAlign = VertAlign.Center;
            footerText.Bounds = new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f,
                19.0f * Units.Centimeters, 0.5f * Units.Centimeters);
            footerText.TextColor = Color.Black;
            footerText.FillColor = Color.Wheat;
            titleText.Border.Color = Color.Black;
            titleText.Border.Lines = BorderLines.All;
            titleText.Border.Width = 4.0f;
            footerText.Text = "Page [Page]";
            page.PageFooter.Objects.Add(footerText);
            // Exporting the report
            report.Prepare();

            PDFSimpleExport pdf = new PDFSimpleExport();
            // Save the report 
            report.Export(pdf, "ExportedPDF.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```